# Login form not validating

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a login form but it does not do the validation rightly against the value in the database. when I put in the wrong password it still redirects me to the page that needs login access

CONTROLLER

```
public function login() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[6]|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        // return main page if submitted form is invalid.

        $this->load->view('abt_login');

    } else {

         $this->load->model('abt_db');
    $q = $this->abt_db->check_login();


    if($q)
    {
        $data = array(
            'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password'      => $this->input->post('password'),
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt-abovetheblues');
    }
    else
    {
       redirect('index.php/abovetheblues/abt_selfhelp');
    }


    }
}
```

MODEL

```
function check_login() {
        $this->load->database();

        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));
        $q = $this->db->get('user');

        if ($q->num_rows == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider passing the two variables to the function instead of trying to grab them from the input class:

**Controller:**

```
$this->load->model('abt_db');
$q = $this->abt_db->check_login($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'));
```

**Model:**

```
function check_login($email, $password) {
    $this->load->database();

    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);  ## VERY UNSECURE - SEE BELOW
    $q = $this->db->get('user');

    if ($q->num_rows() == 1) { ## as seen in the previous answer
        return true;
    }
    return false; ## You NEED to have this. 
}
```

## PLEASE NOTE:

You are checking the password directly with the database in plaintext. This is a ***terrible*** idea and will lead to your application getting compromised.

I strongly recommend you read this excellent primer on password security:

### [Salting Password Hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)

Answer (score 1):

`num_rows` is a function and you not call the function
Try to change this:

```
if ($q->num_rows == 1) {
    return true;
}
```

to this:

```
if ($q->num_rows() == 1) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: try to print what is : $q->num_rows()